How can I set up an iterator in samtools htsjdk?
I'm using samtools htsjdk, and I want to look at a certain range of the file. I already know the location of the gene I'm interested in, and I've found the bin it's in, but I'm trying to find a way to extract the specific region from the file.
I'm trying to do this by iterating through the file until I get to the specific bin, but it keeps on running the issue: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Iteration in progress" because I have to keep the SAMReader open to create the iterator.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
